# MAUI Preview 9 breaks CollectionView update with ObservableCollection?

Tags: xamarin, observablecollection, preview, collectionview, maui

I have the following code which used to work on Android just fine until MAUI Preview 9:

XAML:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel_MyConns}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <Label Text="{Binding LastName}" TextColor="Red"/>
         </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

MVVM code:

```
public class ConnsViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged {
public ObservableCollection<STuser> ViewModel_MyConns { get; }
IList locallist;

// constructor:
public ConnsViewModel() {
    ViewModel_MyConns = new ObservableCollection<STuser>();
    locallist = ReadDataFromDB();
    foreach (var item in locallist) {
        ViewModel_MyConns.Add(item);
    }
}
}
```

Everything used to work fine and I'd get the CollectionView updated with the values I read from the DB.
But now with MAUI Preview 9 this no longer works.

Any ideas/theories/solutions?
Thanks.

(P.S. Since I'm working with an ObservableCollection, there's no need to raise the PropertyChanged event.  But in a desperate attempt to make it work, I fired PropertyChanged all the same, but to no avail).

Comment: And what about using a List ? Does it works ? My ObservableCollection is working fine with preview 9

Comment: @Juan Sturla: Do you mean using a ListView?  Didn't work either. Could you post your code that works, please?

Comment: Yes, I meant a listView. And what if you change the declaration of the Public variable to IEnummerable, and then set the ObservableCollection to it. I will look if I find some code

Comment: @JuanSturla: changing to IEnumerable didn't help.  It would be great to see your code that works.  Thanks.

Comment: For example [this code](https://github.com/juansturla/PokeApiNet/blob/master/PokeApp_Maui8/ViewModels/AllPokemonsViewModel.cs) works fine. But it is just a normal use, northing strange

Comment: @Juan Sturla: Many thanks.  Yes, this essentially looks like my code. 
What does your XAML look like? Also, are you trying this on Android emulator?

Comment: The whole repository is there, feel free to look at it. I am using Android physical device, didn't tried it with the emulator

Comment: @JuanSturla : interestingly, the I've compiled your code and was able to launch it on the emulator, but it's only showing 1 Pokemon.   Also, strangely, the debugger is not breaking at any breakpoints.  Something is strange; wonder if that's an emulator problem...

Comment: Sometimes it get a little buggy and you have to move the collectionView up and down to it correctly. But I guess all that's left is to try on a physical device

Comment: @JuanSturla: yep, I've just ordered a physical phone, which should arrive in a couple of days. Will report of the findings.

Comment: An update: tried it on a physical Android 11 phone, the problem persists.

Comment: That's too bad. I hope that you find a way to fix it/workaround it